# How to calculate the transformation matrix of 3D coordinate system?

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

Now I have many groups of 3D coordinates in 2 different coordinate system and I want to calculate the transformation matrix using these coordinates. For example: the coordinates of point A in those two coordinate systems are (i,j,k) and (x,y,z), separately. So

(i,j,k,1)=(x,y,z,1)*M

the M is what I want, but the matrix are singular so I cannot directly calculate i, so how can I do it?

Comment: With your coordinates, are you sure they are EXACTLY the same, just multiplied by M? How big is the margin for error? How many points there are in one batch, 1, 10, 100, 1000?

Answer (score 0):

First it is better to write the equation like this:

(i,j,k,1) = M*(x,y,z,1)

Now, for every pair of point in your coordinate systems, you have and equation like above, and each equation can be presenter by an equation system with 4 equations and 16 variables that we will call them m11 , m12 , m13 , m14 , m21 , ... , m44. We want to find these variables for a given set of point pares.

So as long as your pair of points are less than 4, you may have more than one solution and for exactly 4 pair of points you get exactly one solution. Now, if there is going to be more that 4 pair of points you may have no solution at all for the equation system.

So beside monitoring the conditions I mentioned above, all you have to do is to solve a system of linear equations. for help about solving a system of linear equation read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

Comment: I'm really sorry. English is not my native language. I fixed it, Thank you.